# Can't compile Ardour: "Can't find -lfftw3f_threads"

Tags: compiling, libraries, c, ardour

I am trying to install Ardour from source. I successfully completed the configuration process after a few failed attempts and installing the required libraries. Now the installation process  cancels with this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3f_threads
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3f_threads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have pasted the full terminal output on [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/cd8Q2MdD)

The the code and ful installation instructions of Ardour can be found [here](https://ardour.org/building_linux.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install common development packages and build-dependencies with

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get build-dep ardour
```

And please note that Ardour [is packaged in Ubuntu repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ardour&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all).

Comment: Thanks I'll just take the easy route out, I will use the one from the Ubuntu repositories.